# How to read both input interface and remote socket address for an UDP datagram received in Golang?

Tags: sockets, go, udp

`PacketConn.ReadFrom()` can provide `ControlMessage` containing the ifIndex for the input interface.

`UDPConn.ReadFromUDP()` returns `net.UDPAddr` with the source socket address (srcIP+srcPort) of the datagram.

However, how to get BOTH informations: input interface ifIndex **AND** remote socket address (srcIP+srcPort) ?

EDIT: I have filled an issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14362

Comment: No, each local interface has its own addresses. However, multiple local interfaces can join the same multicast group. I need to know the exact interface where a datagram addressed to group G was received. Also, I need to know the source address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the underlying socket is UDP, .ReadFrom() returns a *net.UDPAddr object as a net.Addr result.

Thus .ReadFrom() can be used go obtain both input interface (as ifIndex) and remote socket full endpoint address (IPaddr+port within net.UDPAddr).

```
// c is *ipv4.PacketConn

n, cm, srcAddr, err := c.ReadFrom(buf)

switch srcAddr.(type) {
    case *net.UDPAddr:
        udpAddr := srcAddr.(*net.UDPAddr)
}
```